# How can I change the Zoom level of a WinRT WebView?

Tags: webview, zooming, windows-8, windows-runtime

How can I change the zoom level of a WinRT [Webview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview)?

If I give it focus, I can zoom in/out using the keyboard `CTRL+ +`  and `CTRL+ -`
But can this be accomplished from code?

Note: Putting the WebView inside a ScrollViewer, and let that zoom, is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do it *directly* in managed code. There is, however, a workaround if you own the content or can inject some css / script.

In your HTML, add this css:

```css
<style type="text/css">
body
{
zoom:100%;
}
</style>
```

In your HTML also include a script block like this:

```js
function setZoomLevel(newZoom) {
    document.styleSheets[0]['rules'][0].style['zoom'] = newZoom;
}
```

In your C# code, add a helper method:

```cs
private void SetZoomLevel(int level)
{
    string slevel = string.Format("{0}%", level);
    webBrowser.InvokeScript("setZoomLevel", slevel);
}
```

In your C# code you can now adjust the zoom level by calling:

```cs
SetZoomLevel(200);
```

That's the best I could find and unfortunately it doesn't work if you can't inject a style and some script.

**NOTE:** Although this does zoom content in pretty much the same way as adjusting the zoom slider, the zoom slider is not affected in the desktop browser. Therefore if you call **SetZoomLevel(200);** above and then set the slider to 200% you would actually see 400%. This should not be an issue in WebView because there *is* no slider.

Hope someone comes up with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm, good question.  I was looking into the [ITransformProvider2 interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448824(v=vs.85).aspx) which is part of the accessibility APIs and gives you programmatic zooming functionality for desktop and Metro apps, but since WebView is sealed I'm afraid it won't be too useful.  Posting this info anyway in case it helps someone else make progress.

Magnus, just out of curiosity, why won't the ScrollViewer solution work for you?